# Copy above row values below

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Probably easy, but couldn't find it.

Want to copy large chunk of data in row where concat data wasn't properly filled in so NaN is below values.

Small example:

```
df1 = {'col1': ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)
```

Did this:

```
df1['col1'][7:14] = df1['col1'][0:7]
```

Worked fine.

But what about larger data sets where I don't know the index slicing? Is there a built-in function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 1) not to chain index, 2) passing numpy array on assignment:

```
df.loc[7:14, 'col1'] = df.loc[:7,'col1'].values
```

Output:

```
   col1
0     a
1     b
2     c
3     d
4     e
5     f
6     g
7     a
8     b
9     c
10    d
11    e
12    f
13    g
```

Comment: What if I don't know where the split is from values and NaN, if there were 20,000 rows or something?